# How to integrate using known distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

I'm having trouble figuring this integration out using known distributions. I don't know which distribution to use to solve this problem. It looks like a gamma to me.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{3}e^{-x^2}dx$$

I tried substituting $u=x^{2}$ to simplify the problem but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What is the pdf of the normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $1/{2}$?

Comment: You have $-x^2$ not $-x$ in the exponential.  Do you know a distribution for something like that?

Comment: You could also substitute $u = x^2$ and then do integration by parts...

Comment: Consider the derivative of $e^{-x^2}$ and the derivative of $x^2 e^{-x^2}$

Comment: @GEdgar Would it be Rayleigh distribution?

Comment: @MichaelBiro I wish, I need to do it by using known distributions

Comment: If you know the moments of the Rayleigh distribution, that will do it.

Comment: @GEdgar thanks! Any tips on figuring out these distributions quickly? What should I be looking for when deciding which distribution to use?

Answer (score 2):

Substitution $u=x^2$ leads to:$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{3}e^{-x^{2}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}ue^{-u}du=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}U$$
where $U$ has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda=1$ (so $\mathbb E(U)=\frac{1}{\lambda}=1$)

Comment: Could you explain how substituting $u=x^{2}$ made $x^{3}$ into just $u$?

Comment: $u du = x^2 d(x^2) = x^2 2xdx = 2x^3 dx$

Comment: + 1 in return  :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can integrate by parts twice.  First use $u = x^2$, $v = e^{-x^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you can integrate by parts:

$\displaystyle I=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{3}e^{-x^2}dx,\quad u = x^2, v' = xe^{-x^2}, u'=2x, v = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}$

$\displaystyle I=\left[-x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}\right]_{0}^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\left[e^{-x^2}\right]\int_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

If you substitute $u = x^2$, you get $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty ue^{-u} du$.

Here, $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty u e^{-u} du = 1$ because $ue^{-u}$ is the pdf of $\Gamma(2,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The term $e^{-x^2}$ does not come up in a Gamma distribution but in a Normal distribution with mean $μ=0$ and variance $σ^2$ such that $$2σ^2=1 \iff σ^2=\frac12$$ The term $x^3$ links to the $E[X^3]$, but the integration limits are not over the entire $\mathbb R$ but only from $0$ to $\infty$. However, knowing that $$E[X^k]=0$$ for every odd $k$, where $X \sim N(μ=0, σ^2=\frac12)$, and due to the symmetry of the normal distribution of $X$ over $μ=0$ you can conclude that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^3e^{-x^2}dx=\frac12$$

Comment: @drhab Oh, thanks. I gave you a +1 too.